# Can i Read RTF and Doc File Using Open Xml?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

Is it possible to read RTF and Doc Files using OpenXml? 
or do i need to convert it into Docx Format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think i found the answer. As of my understanding OpenXml doesn't allow to read RTF and old Doc  file. may be because it is not in the XML format . New Docx files are in XML Formats following the standards of OpenXml. therefore Docx file can be read by OpenXml